# vim: show diff on W11 (file changed since editing started)

Tags: vim

when a file is changed and I'm working on it, vim prompts me two choices:

```
W11: Warning: File "foo.bar" has changed since editing started
See ":help W11" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File:
```

Is there a way to make it show me a diff between the buffer contents and what's on disk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Place the following in your .vimrc file taken from `:h :DiffOrig`

```
command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis | wincmd p | diffthis
```

Then when prompted hit `o` for ok and then execute `:DiffOrig`. You will be presented with the diff.

If you decide that you want to take the file from disk execute `:e!` to reload the file from disk.

Quick overview of `:DiffOrig`

Vertically split a new buffer and read in the file in question from disk and mark both buffers to be diffed.

Glory of detail for `:DiffOrig`

- `:vert {cmd}` will execute any {cmd} and any splits will be split vertically.
- `new` open a new split with a new buffer
- `set bt=nofile` set `'buftype'` to `nofile` so no file will be written to disk
- `r` is short for `:read {file}`. `r #` reads in to the buffer the alternative file, which is the buffer that was just split from. This alternative file is the file in question being read from disk.
- `0d_` which is short for `0delete _`. When the alternative file is read in it leaves a blank line at top. `0delete _` will remove the top line into the black hole register so it does not mess with other registers.
- `diffthis` set buffer to diffed.
- `windcmd p` switches back to the previous window. This is the same as `<c-w>p` in normal mode.
- `diffthis` this sets the changed buffer to be included into the diff set.

For more information:

```
:h :DiffOrig
:h :e
:h :diff
:h vert
:h new
:h r
:h d
:h "_
:h windcmd
:h diffthis
:h :c_#
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Now if there was a way to make it automatic... :) (i.e., be prompted with a third choice when W11 is emitted)

Comment: @Andrea Spadaccini: Sorry I am not aware of anyway to make this automatic.